# How to sum item's quantity separately in v-for(VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm learning to code(really noob) with VueJS and I got really stuck here

I have a list of orders, and I want to sum the quantity of each item apart. The only access to the items is through v-for.

```
<tr>

<td data-th="list">

<tr v-for="(order,key) in list" :order="order" :key="key">

<li v-for="(item,key) in order.detail" :item="item" :key="item.title">{{ item.quantity }} {{ item.title }} </li> 

</tr>
</td>
    </tr>
```

The data is organized like this

```
"list" : {
    "Order1" : {
    "detail" : [ { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Tomato"
                  }, 
                  { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Banana"
                  } ],
                },
    "Order2" : {
    "detail" : [ { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Banana"
                  }]
                },
    "Order3" : {
    "detail" : [ { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Tomato"
                  }]
                },
          }
```

Now I'm getting something like this:

1 Tomato
1 Banana
1 Banana
1 Tomato

But I want to get this:
2 Banana
2 Tomato

Comment: You can calculate sum inside the method property and then render it to the view.

Comment: Use `.reduce` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: If I use .reduce it won't differenciate between items, It's going to sum every quantity without differentiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!

Using filters in Vue, I get to this.

```
filters: {

   sumProducts: function(list) {
        var products= [];

          Object.keys(list).forEach(key => {
            var order = list[key];
            var orderDetail = order.detail;
                for(let i=0; i < orderDetail.length; i++) {
                    var item = orderDetail[i];
                      if(products[item.title] != undefined){
                        products[item.title] += item.quantity;
                      } else {
                        products[item.title] = item.quantity;
                      }
                }
          }) ;
          return products;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use script tags or external javascript files with .js extension. then, you would most likely not need more help in this case

And yes, maybe .reduce can solve your problem as Adriano Resende says

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this function to get the sums for each product then show:

```
var list = {
    "Order1" : {
    "detail" : [ { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Tomato"
                  }, 
                  { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Banana"
                  } ],
                },
    "Order2" : {
    "detail" : [ { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Banana"
                  }]
                },
    "Order3" : {
    "detail" : [ { "quantity" : 1,
                    "title" : "Tomato"
                  }]
                },
          };

function sum_products(list){
  var products = [];
    for(var order in list){
        var orderDetail = list[order].detail;
        for(var i in orderDetail){
          var item = orderDetail[i];
          if(products[item.title] != undefined){
            products[item.title] += item.quantity;
          } else {
            products[item.title] = item.quantity;
          }
        }
    }
    return products;
}
console.log(sum_products(list));
```

Comment: Thank you! It's much more clear for me now. I almost have it, I'm still having some problems with the syntax I think.

I get this from console: 
"TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined"